# print all variables in class C#

Tags: c#, class, variables

To start I would prefer not to use reflection to accomplish this.

I have a class lets say

```
public class exampleClass
{
  public string var1 = "one";
  public string var2 = "two";
  public int var3 = 3;
  public string var4 = "four";
  etc. etc..
}
```

I want to dynamically be able to iterate through that class and print out the variables. I thought about serialization but wasn't exactly sure how to implement it for this case (the only examples I could find were to XML and I don't want that) also I don't really want to change the structure of the class in any way.

The reason I'm doing that is because I'm constructing an HTML table and want to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < exampleClass.Count; i++)
  tbl_row = "<td>" + exampleClass[i] + "</td>";
```

or something similar. Any suggestions?

Comment: Curious:  why the aversion to `System.Reflection`?

Comment: Technically speaking, these are fields, not variables and the easiest way to read them is using reflection

Comment: Trying to keep with the coding practice of the project and Reflection isn't used anywhere else. Also prefer to keep the references to a minimum. I also tried reflection and get a null reference exception when I do it. I can post that if you want (but would still like to see an alternative)

Comment: Maybe using some kind of [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) like with [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) would help?

Comment: Maybe not a helpful suggestion, but if the coding standards allow for public fields (variables) in classes, then I'd suggest the coding standards need updating and you should feel free to use reflection...

Comment: There isn't an alternative to reflection in this case, not to achieve what you want. You can do things like this in javascript because all objects are effectively associative arrays. That isn't the case in C#, there's nothing to iterate over. You're going to have to either use reflection or explicitly write each cell in the table-row one at a time.

Comment: @Chris I thought that might be the case. was hoping for an alternative. I guess I'll end up using reflection.

Comment: You can use `TagBuilder` to construct your HTML. Check my answer for a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easisets way would be *using* reflection. This should be enough :

```
var example =  new exampleClass();

var allPublicFields = example.GetType().
       GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
```

Use a dictionary, instead of fields: `Dictionary<fieldName, fieldValue>` , but this is 
kind *over* engineering the simple a streghtforward solution: reflection over clear and maintanable structure of your strong typed class.

Answer (score 2):

Complete same for building HTML with [`TagBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.aspx).

```
var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("tr");
var exampleClass =  new exampleClass();

tagBuilder.InnerText += "<td>Field</td><td>Value</td>";

foreach(var field in typeof(exampleClass)
                         .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    var nameBuilder = new TagBuilder("td");
    var valueBuilder = new TagBuilder("td");

    nameBuilder.InnerHtml = field.Name;
    valueBuilder.InnerHtml = field.GetValue(exampleClass).ToString();

    tagBuilder.InnerHtml += string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                          nameBuilder.ToString(),
                                          valueBuilder.ToString());
}
```

outputs:

```
<tr>
    <td>Field</td><td>Value</td>
    <td>var1</td><td>one</td>
    <td>var2</td><td>two</td>
    <td>var3</td><td>3</td>
    <td>var4</td><td>four</td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use reflection, how about storing the data in a dictionary, rather than in a custom class? That way you can simply iterate over the keys or values as required.

Comment: goes against the format of the code. It's a view model and used elsewhere as is so I don't want to break code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you're better off with reflection. You could achieve what you're trying to do if you're using .NET 4 or later and derive `exampleClass` from [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx).

The [example on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex.aspx) is pretty similar to what you're looking to do.

Comment: While using DynamicObject is certainly a way to achieve this kind of functionality, it's worth noting that the questioner did state "I don't really want to change the structure of the class in any way". I would assume changing which class exampleClass inherits from would go against this requirement.

Comment: Oops, I missed that :)  My suggestion is academic, I wouldn't recommend using `DynamicObject` in this instance anyway.